# Loading QGIS external processing tools into Python environment

Tags: pyqgis, installation

I'm looking to run some QGIS algorithms in a separate python environment (not the one built in to QGIS) and would like to use some externally provided processing tools (ie. FUSION, LAStools, UMEP etc). I've been able to get an environment working (I'm using Python 3 in Spyder through Anaconda, and QGIS 3.16) and can access the built in processing tools, but can't figure out how to add these additional tools.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have added some info on this on our website (https://umep-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UMEPforProcessing.html). You need to add some lines of code to import the tools correctly:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
import sys

# Initiating a QGIS application
qgishome = 'C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/'
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgishome, True)
app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()

# import third party processing plugins
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\ **your_username** \AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins')
from processing_umep.processing_umep_provider import ProcessingUMEPProvider
umep_provider = ProcessingUMEPProvider()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(umep_provider)
```